# Combine two scatter plots with different data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a requirement where I want to combine two different scatter plot in the same plot area. One scatter plot is with metric 1 and another scatter plot with metric 2. 
Is it feasible in R ?
I have added the dataset as well as code. But not sure how to merge these two within the same plot.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Product = c("A","B","C"),
                  ProductMetric =  c("85","90","92"),
                  CategoryMetric = c("83"),
                  Category = c("AAA"))
df1
ggplot(data=df1, mapping= aes(x=Category,y= ProductMetric))+ geom_point(size=5)+
  ggplot(data=df1, mapping= aes(x=Category,y= CategoryMetric))+ geom_point(size=5)
```

So basically after the combined result, there should be 4 circles in the same chart, Basically I want to show Product Avg and Category Avg with the circle in the same chart so that end user can compare the product avg with the category avg by just seeing the chart.

Regards,
Akash

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to convert your data from `wide` to `long` format using `gather` from the `tidyr` package. Read more [here](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/)

```r
library(dplyr)  
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(Product = c("A","B","C"),
                  ProductMetric =  c("85","90","92"),
                  CategoryMetric = c("83"),
                  Category = c("AAA"))
df1

#>   Product ProductMetric CategoryMetric Category
#> 1       A            85             83      AAA
#> 2       B            90             83      AAA
#> 3       C            92             83      AAA

df1_long <- df1 %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Category, -Product)
df1_long

#>   Product Category            key value
#> 1       A      AAA  ProductMetric    85
#> 2       B      AAA  ProductMetric    90
#> 3       C      AAA  ProductMetric    92
#> 4       A      AAA CategoryMetric    83
#> 5       B      AAA CategoryMetric    83
#> 6       C      AAA CategoryMetric    83

ggplot(df1_long, aes(x = Category, y = value, color = key)) + geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Edit: to keep `Category Ave` color in `red` while changing the color and legend for each `Product` dynamically depending on the number of products.

```r
myCol <- c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(unique(df1$Product)), "Set2"), "red")

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Product, y = ProductMetric, color = Product)) + geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(y = CategoryMetric, color = "Category Ave"), size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual("Legend", 
                     labels = c(paste0("Product ", df1$Product), "Category Ave"),
                     values = myCol)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Category, y = ProductMetric, color = Product)) + geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(y = CategoryMetric, color = "Category Ave"), size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual("Legend", 
                     labels = c(paste0("Product ", df1$Product), "Category Ave"),
                     values = myCol)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I would like to change the color for each product dynamically. and keep Category avg as "Red"

Comment: I mean three different color for 3 products.. :)

Answer (score 3):

We can add a new `geom_point` layer and specify `data` to be `df1` and `y` to be `CategoryMetric`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = Category, y = ProductMetric)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_point(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = Category, y = CategoryMetric), size = 5, color = "red")
```

[image]