# How to plot two different y value in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset look like this

```
COUNTY == c(COUNTY1, COUNTY2, COUNTY3)
PERC_2012 == c(5%, 6%, 12%)
PERC_2017 == c(55%, 67%, 67%)
data.frame(COUNTY, PERC_2012, PERC2017)
```

How do I plot x = county and a separate line for perc 2012 and 2017?
Thank you

Comment: See these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49595356/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871624/786542

Comment: Please show the code you've attempted so far so we can see where you got stuck.  Your dataset code is a nice start but that code won't run in R as is (assuming you are working in R).

Comment: this is the code i used so far
ggplot(county) + geom_area(aes(x = COUNTY, y= PERC_2012)) + geom_area(aes(x=county, y=PERC_2017)). 
it plotted the graph with county as x axie and perc_2012 as y, but can't show both perc_2012 and perc_2017
thank you

Comment: Thank you Tung!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: 1]

Were you looking for something like this?

#### Code

```
ggplot(county) + 
    geom_area(aes(COUNTY, Value, group = PERC, fill = PERC))
```

#### Data

```
COUNTY <- c("COUNTY1", "COUNTY2", "COUNTY3")
PERC_2012 <- c(.05, .06, .12)
PERC_2017 <- c(.55, .67, .67)

county <- data.frame(COUNTY, PERC_2012, PERC_2017)

library(dplyr)
county <- county %>% 
    gather("PERC", "Value", -COUNTY)
```